# Reformat and Convert xlsx to csv - xlrd.open_work workaround

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, xlrd

I have a larger script that is supposed to read xlsx files, reformat and convert to csv files. But the code was written a few years ago and uses the xlrd module to open the Excel files but apparently the xlrd module no longer supports xlsx files. I am looking for a workaround to the xlrd error to update the script. The .xlsx files are in the same folder as the python script. I've narrowed down the issue to the snippet below.

```
def xls2csv(xlsfn, csvfn, xlsx2csv=None):
    """ """
    with xlrd.open_workbook(xlsfn) as wb:
       sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
       with open(csvfn, 'w', newline="") as f:   
           c = csv.writer(f)
           for r in range(sh.nrows):
               c.writerow(sh.row_values(r))
```

Comment: Per here [xlrd](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) the answer is to use one of the alternatives listed here [Python-Excel](https://www.python-excel.org/)